In Civil War, which faction killed Sammy?
In the 2024 movie Civil War a group of soldiers killed Sammy and a bunch of other people, was it a U.S. or Western Forces soldier that did it?

It would seem that the soldiers at the mass grave, where Sammy
was killed, were loyalist (U.S.) soldiers. Wikipedia describes them as such; bold emphasis is mine:

 “Tony and Jessie playfully switch vehicles, only for Bohai and Jessie to be captured by loyalist death squads dumping civilian corpses in a mass grave.”

His character also coldly asks:

“What kind of an American are you?”

Which is clearly what the loyalists would say. Mind you, we don’t encounter the “good guy”
Western Forces until later on in the film.
The Western Forces were clearly friendlier and more reasonable than Jesse Plemmons and his mass murdering death squad jerks.
